# Why can't we add maximum functionality in the Kernel of an operating system?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, computer-science

I was reading a book by "Andrew S.Tanenbaum" in which he mentions that :

"MINIX was one of the first UNIX-like systems based on a microkernel design.
The idea behind a microkernel is to provide minimal functionality in the kernel to
make it reliable and efficient. Consequently, memory management and the file system
were pushed out into user processes."

Does that mean "kernels with maximum functionality" will not be reliable and efficient ? 
Why is it so please explain with help of an example.

Thanks

Comment: How has the author defined the terms "reliable" and "efficient" within the context of the book prior to reading that section?

Comment: Read also [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and before that the wikipage on [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)

Comment: A typical example of [monolithic kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel) is the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) which is in practice fairly successful, reliable, and efficient (and has a *lot* of functionalities). You should try to install some [linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your own computer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if monolithic kernels ( which have more functionality ) are reliable and efficient then why has the author in the book said "...kernels with minimum functionality are efficient and reliable " ?

Comment: Because that very question was and still is a **hot matter of debate**. Read about [Tanenbaum-Torvalds debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanenbaum%E2%80%93Torvalds_debate)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think the part that really gets debated is which one is the "better" or "correct" design decision, rather than, say, which one offers more/less functionality, performance, reliability. For example, monolithic kernels will be faster simply due to the reduced overhead of function calls vs IPC, and I don't think anyone debates that. What I've seen Torvalds say in interview is that for "the real world" you need a monolithic one b/c micros are too slow. While true, if the other author considers speed *secondary* to other concerns, then a different decision will be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a subtle, but important, aspect to understanding this question depends on how the terms "reliable" and "efficient" are defined. For this answer, I'll use the following general definitions:

- **reliable:** difficult or less likely to malfunction or otherwise break/crash
- **efficient:** to require the least amount of *time* to complete some task, even at the expense of space

While not everyone will define the terms in the same way (e.g. in an embedded system, using the least amount of *space* might be considered more "efficient"), in most instances, I think users tend to be biased towards speed.

> The idea behind a microkernel is to provide minimal functionality in the kernel to make it reliable and efficient.

I think the important part here is "minimal functionality". Having a minimum amount of functionality implies that the amount of code that has to be written, read, and maintained/debugged, is less than one with more stuff in it.

In this sense, and given my definitions above, less code means the kernel overall is smaller, likely simpler, and easier to work with. The simpler a system is, the easier it is to spot potential/actual issues, making the system more "reliable" in that sense. This reduces the chances of new hidden bugs making it into the codebase and breaking something later.

It can also make it more "efficient" (i.e. faster) because the system will have less overhead processing to take care of in order to keep itself functioning correctly. In other words: the less you have to work, the less time you'll need to spend working.

By analogy, imagine you're reading a book; the less pages you need to read to complete the book, the simpler the story-line will be to understand, and the faster you'll get to finish it.

> Does that mean "kernels with maximum functionality" will not be reliable and efficient?

Not necessarily, though it depends on what "maximum functionality" means. For example, would having a media player, email client, and word processor inside the kernel help it achieve "maximum functionality"? Maybe. Does it make sense? No.

For this discussion, I'll use the following definition:

- **maximum functionality:** compatibility with the maximum amount of hardware possible

In practical terms this means that if you were to swap some component A for some other component B (i.e. network card), the machine should continue working fine, rather than refusing to boot.

In this sense, the kernel could have "maximum functionality" without *completely* sacrificing "efficiency and reliability".

Code would need to be added in order for the kernel to allow components to be identified, their drivers loaded, and so on, which would increase both the chances of bugs being introduced as code gets written and the amount of processing overhead to take care of the added functionality. And even then, most bugs will only be temporary.

So, as you can see, there's a trade-off. So, what about the micro-kernel?

The micro-kernel specifically seeks to manage this trade-off by pushing less critical "services" to the outside of the kernel... which in turn means that things that would normally have the ability to crash a kernel (e.g. a bad driver), and therefore the whole machine, get pushed outside as well. This limits the amount of disruption they can cause if/when they mis-behave.

Once outside the kernel, they run as user-space applications (e.g. similar to notepad) instead of kernel-space (e.g. graphics card driver in a monolithic kernel), and if any of those services or applications were to have problems and crash, the machine itself is more likely to survive instead of displaying a BSoD or equivalent.

For example, if a text editor crashes, only the application is shutdown. If a graphics card driver running in kernel space crashes, then you'll likely need to reboot.

But as I mentioned, it's a trade-off. For example, moving kernel functionality outside into user-land does incur some efficiency/speed penalties. What used to be a simple function call in a monolithic kernel (e.g. Linux) within the same process in kernel space now needs to go through the overhead of inter-process communication with multiple independent tasks outside of itself, which requires more context switches between them, and time, before the task can be completed.

By analogy, imagine you're reading a book with multiple characters that make important decisions at key points in the story, but this *main* book only focuses on the *main* character, and the consequences of these decisions for the *supporting* characters are dealt with in separate side-story books. The main book itself will be shorter and simpler, but the fact that you have to constantly keep switching between books to actually read everything means it'll take you more time to complete it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but when you have systems functions ( i.e file management ) running as user processes won't they be less secure ?

Comment: @Ahti I think it depends. The level of security needs to be examined within the context of some threat model, but what we can say is that, if the process is running in user-space, rather than in kernel-space, the *scope* of the damage caused by a compromised process will be more limited. It's like running a server process as the `root` vs its own separate user account, like `apache`. If the user `apache` is compromised, the scope of the damage is more limited than if the `root` user is compromised.